# Discord bot displaying token as SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

Whenever I run my bots code I get a SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input.

I don't see any open brackets so I was wondering if any of you could see the issue.

My code is as follows:

```
const request = require('request');
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
});
client.on('message', msg => {
  if (!msg.content.startsWith(prefix) || msg.author.bot) return;

  const args = msg.content.slice(prefix.length).split(' ');
  const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();
  if (msg.author.bot) return;
  if (msg.content === `${prefix}ping`) {
    msg.reply('Pong!');
  }

  if (msg.content === `${prefix}rule`) {
    msg.reply('rules are not yet implemented, check out https://5thsrd.org/ for rules in the meantime');
  }

  if (msg.content.startswith(`${prefix}spell`)) {
    request(`http://www.dnd5eapi.co/api/spells/${args}`, { json: true }, (err, res, body) => {
      if (err) { return console.log(err); }
      else if (command === 'spell')
        msg.channel.send(`Name: ${body.name}`);
      msg.channel.send(`${body.desc}`);
      msg.channel.send(`At Higher Levels: ${body.higher_level}`)

      if (msg.content.startsWith(`${prefix}class`)) {
        request(`http://www.dnd5eapi.co/api/classes/${args}`, { json: true }, (err, res, body) => {
          if (err) { return console.log(err); }
          else if (command === 'class')
            msg.channel.send(`Name: ${body.name}`);
          msg.channel.send(`Hit Dice:${body.hit_die}`);
          msg.channel.send(`Proficiency Options: ${body.proficiency_choices}`);
          msg.channel.send(`Starting Equipment: ${body.starting_equipment}`);
          msg.channel.send(`Proficiencies: ${body.proficiencies}`);
          msg.channel.send(`Subclasses: ${body.subclasses}`);

        });

      }
    })
  }
});
client.login(token);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use any [online JavaScript "beautifier"](https://beautifier.io/), [linter](https://jslint.com/), or any IDE worth it's weight, you'd quickly become aware that you actually haven't closed your functions out correctly.

You're missing 2 things:

1. A curly close brace (`}`) for your `` if (msg.content.startswith(`${prefix}spell`)) `` statement.
2. A curly close brace (`}`), a close parenthesis (`)`), and a semicolon (`;`) to close out your `client.on('message', msg => {` block.

All in all, your fixed up code should look like:

```
const request = require('request');
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
});
client.on('message', msg => {
    if (!msg.content.startsWith(prefix) || msg.author.bot) return;

    const args = msg.content.slice(prefix.length).split(' ');
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();
    if (msg.author.bot) return;
    if (msg.content === `${prefix}ping`) {
        msg.reply('Pong!');
    }

    if (msg.content === `${prefix}rule`) {
        msg.reply('rules are not yet implemented, check out https://5thsrd.org/ for rules in the meantime');
    }

    if (msg.content.startswith(`${prefix}spell`)) {
        request(`http://www.dnd5eapi.co/api/spells/${args}`, {
            json: true
        }, (err, res, body) => {
            if (err) {
                return console.log(err);
            } else if (command === 'spell')
                msg.channel.send(`Name: ${body.name}`);
            msg.channel.send(`${body.desc}`);
            msg.channel.send(`At Higher Levels: ${body.higher_level}`)

            if (msg.content.startsWith(`${prefix}class`)) {
                request(`http://www.dnd5eapi.co/api/classes/${args}`, {
                    json: true
                }, (err, res, body) => {
                    if (err) {
                        return console.log(err);
                    } else if (command === 'class')
                        msg.channel.send(`Name: ${body.name}`);
                    msg.channel.send(`Hit Dice:${body.hit_die}`);
                    msg.channel.send(`Proficiency Options: ${body.proficiency_choices}`);
                    msg.channel.send(`Starting Equipment: ${body.starting_equipment}`);
                    msg.channel.send(`Proficiencies: ${body.proficiencies}`);
                    msg.channel.send(`Subclasses: ${body.subclasses}`);

                });

            }
        });
    }
});

client.login(token);
```